# RHEL 8.3: Toggle Top Icons Plus Gnome extension in Tweak Tool with script

Tags: tweak, gnome-shell-extensions, rhel8

Is there a way to toggle the Gnome Extension Top Icons Plus in Tweak Tool in a script?

Currently I am unable to find any APIs provided by Tweak Tool or Top Icons Plus.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable the extension via:

`gnome-shell-extension-tool -e <UUID>`

so in your case:

`gnome-shell-extension-tool -e TopIcons@phocean.net`

extension must be located either in

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

or extensions shipped with RHEL installed via rpm are usually located:

`/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

Comment: With newer versions, you should use `gnome-extensions enable <UUID>`
But unfortunately, topicons is no longer compatible with latest gnome-shell..